# Pandas groupby: efficiently extract indexes

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby, point-clouds

I am trying to efficiently split a 3D point cloud into a number of 2D tiles/segments.

Using a combination of numpy's searchsorted() and pandas groupby() functions i have been able to achieve sorting the data into groups with pleasing speed.

For example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import time

scale=100
n_points= 1000000
n_tiles = 1000000

pos = np.empty((n_points,3))
pos[:,0]=np.random.random(n_points)*scale
pos[:,1]=np.random.random(n_points)*scale
pos[:,2]=np.random.random(n_points)

df = pd.DataFrame(pos)

# create bounds for each segment
min_bound,max_bound = 0,scale
x_segment_bounds,xstep = np.linspace(min_bound, max_bound, num=n_tiles**0.5,retstep = True)
x_segment_bounds[0]=x_segment_bounds[0]+xstep/2
y_segment_bounds,ystep = np.linspace(min_bound, max_bound, num=n_tiles**0.5,retstep=True)
y_segment_bounds[0]=y_segment_bounds[0]+ystep/2

# sort into bins
time_grab = time.clock()
bins_x = np.searchsorted(x_segment_bounds, pos[:, 0])
bins_y = np.searchsorted(y_segment_bounds, pos[:, 1])
print("Time for binning: ", time.clock()-time_grab)

df["bins_x"] = bins_x.astype(np.uint16)
df["bins_y"] = bins_y.astype(np.uint16)

# group points
time_grab = time.clock()
segments = df.groupby(['bins_x', 'bins_y'])
print("Time for grouping: ", time.clock()-time_grab)
```

Produces:

```
Time for binning:  0.1390
Time for grouping:  0.0043
```

The problem i am having is in efficiently accessing the point indexes that belong to each group in the pandas groupby object.

For example looping through each group is very inefficient:

```
segment_indices = []
for i,segment in enumerate(segments):
    segment_indices.append(segment[1].index.values)
```

takes ~70 seconds.

I have found this method for retrieving the indexes:

```
segments = df.groupby(['bins_x', 'bins_y']).apply(lambda x: x.index.tolist())
```

which takes ~10 seconds, however it is still comparatively quite slow compared to the binning and grouping functions. Since i'm simply trying to copy the data to a new array or list, and not actually performing any computation on it, i am expecting much better efficiency. I would expect speeds at least similar to the binning and grouping operations.

I am curious if there is a more efficient way of extracting the indexes (or any of the information) from a groupby object? Alternatively is there another method for segmenting/ grouping points which doesn't use pandas, such as a numpy or scipy alternative?

Comment: Just a note on GroupBy performance: [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) mention that "no splitting occurs until it’s needed. Creating the GroupBy object only verifies that you’ve passed a valid mapping." So calling `groupby()` will always be fast; it's the subsequent aggregation functions that will depend on the size of your input data.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. So no computation is actually performed until a subsequent function is called. I did think it seemed extremely fast for splitting the data into 1 million groups. In that case i may look a little deeper into numpy alternatives..